# Logical tree depth exceeded while traversing the tree

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, navigation

I'm currently building a WPF application and im having trouble navigating back to the MainWindow from my pages.

I'm able to navigate back to previous pages (Q2 to Q1, compiledpage to Q1/Q2) but not to the MainWindow itself.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs** (Window)

```
private void startTroubleshootButton_Clicknew(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // instantiate the Q1 page and assign it to "pg1" variable
    Q1 pg1 = new Q1();

    // Sets the current content control view to Q1 page
    this.Content = pg1;
}
```

**Q1.xaml.cs** (page)

```
private void naviQ2ButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     // instantiate mainwindow and store it in the window variable
     var window = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;

     // instantiate Q2 page and pass the string variable "sb" as arguments to Q2 page/class
     Q2 pg2 = new Q2(sb.ToString());

     // set the current content control to Q2 page
     window.Content = pg2;
}
```

**Q2.xaml.cs** (page)

```
private void compileButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // instantiate mainwindow and store it in the window variable
    var window = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;

    // instantiate  compiledpage and pass the string variable "sb" and valueFromQ1 as arguments to compiledpage/class
    Compiledpage pg3 = new Compiledpage(sb.ToString(), valueFromQ1); 

    // Show compiledpage in the current window
    window.Content = pg3;
}
```

**compiledpage.xaml.cs** (page)

```
private void backButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MainWindow pg = new MainWindow();
    var window = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
    window.Content = pg;  //<- this doesn't work
}
```

Error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Logical tree depth exceeded while traversing the tree. This could indicate a cycle in the tree.'

The back button click of compiledpage was supposed to go back to the MainWindow window but it doesn't seem to work as the error above shows up. Is there a better way to code this or is my navigation approach is just wrong in general? Thanks.

Comment: A very commonly used way to implement navigation is viewmodel first. Using datatemplates associated with viewmodel datatype to template from a viewmodel.  You should be able to google numerous examples but here's one i wrote https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/52485.wpf-tips-and-tricks-using-contentcontrol-instead-of-frame-and-page-for-navigation.aspx

Comment: Thanks. If i am building just a small WPF application that needs simple navigation between views, should i implement MVVM or is that just overkill? Also, if i were to implement MVVM, or should i use a MVVM framework like Caliburn Micro/ MVVM light or would following your example be enough? I honestly want the simplest and least complex method if possible.

Comment: I far prefer mvvmlight to caliburn micro where things mysteriously join up by convention based on matching a magic string. Datatemplating is pretty straight forward really associate a viewmodel type with a view in a few lines of xaml and that part is done. Binding commands is a bit wordy maybe but you can just copy paste https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx